STM32F4 EtherNet/IP library
I'm looking to use an STM32F407I for EtherNet/IP protocol communication with some industrial motors and sensors.
I cannot seem to find a library that would help me do that for my STM32F4.
I found this, but I didn't understand how to use the solution that's suggested
Any help on finding a library would be greatly appreciated.
I looked around and only found the link that's mentioned above.

You can use LwIP for the network stack.

Doesn't LwIP use the standard TCP/IP protocol without the CIP protocol included?
